# Which of the NIPS 2014 papers are most significant, and why?

Tags: machine-learning, research, state-of-the-art

As a newcomer to the field, I find many of the [NIPS 2014 papers](http://papers.nips.cc/book/advances-in-neural-information-processing-systems-27-2014) fascinating, but it is difficult for me to evaluate which ones represent real progress over current approaches.

Which papers do you think are most significant and are likely to have a major impact?

Comment: for 2013: https://www.quora.com/What-were-the-scientific-highlights-of-NIPS-2013

Comment: These questions are generally considered too broad for SE, being mostly opinion-based

Answer (score 4):

The [awards](https://nips.cc/Conferences/2014/Awards) went to "[Asymmetric LSH (ALSH) for Sublinear Time Maximum Inner Product Search (MIPS)](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/5329-asymmetric-lsh-alsh-for-sublinear-time-maximum-inner-product-search-mips)" by Anshumali Shrivastava and Ping Li and "[A* Sampling](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/5449-a-sampling)" by Chris J. Maddison, Daniel Tarlow, and Tom Minka.
Further Quora discussion can be found [here](http://www.quora.com/What-were-the-scientific-highlights-of-the-NIPS-2014).